# easier way to flatten or merge php array than this?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, flatten

I have an array of arrays.

For example:

```
$array[] = array("1", "2", "3");
$array[] = array("5", "9", "ok");
$array[] = array("test", "ok", 8");
```

What is the easiest way of flattening/merging this to just one array?

Result should be:

```
$array = array("1", "2", "3", "5", "9", "ok", "test", "ok", "8");
```

Is there an easier/simpler way to get this result than doing the below?

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
  foreach ($subarray as $value) {
    array_push($result, $value);
  }
}
```

Comment: see here http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since PHP 5.6 you may use `...` operator to provide arguments:

```
array_merge(...$array)
```

**Old answer**

As suggested, you may use `array_merge` for this. If you don't know how many values in your `$array` you may use something like this:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Comment: Instead of the code above you can also write ``array_merge(...$array)``. The 3 dots need to be exactly like this. It's called the [variadic functions operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics).

Comment: array_merge($array1,...$array2); helped me out thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) would fit the bill.

```
$result = array_merge($array[1], $array[2], $array[3], ..., $array[N]);
```

Or if you insist on iteration:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $nested) {
     $result = array_merge($result, $nested);
}
```